# PhpStorm xdebug deep debug not working

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm working with PhpStorm and IntelliJ, xdebug, fpm.

I recently installed xdebug, but I encountered a problem: breakpoints are hit but only if they are in the main file or function. Sometimes I can step in functions but I can't debug deep in the code (just 2 or 3 function calls).

Here is my configuration in `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini`

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9009
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
zend.enable_gc=0
```

[image: Configuration in IntelliJ]

I'd like to get some help about this problem...

Comment: Try adding `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 400;` to your php.ini files config for XDEBUG

Comment: The debugger still stops. On the client side apache tells: 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: It was only a suggestion, I dont use PHPStorm. But I would bet if you look at the XDEBUG manual you will get some clues. Does PHPStorm keep its own version of `php.ini` or does it get the standard one?

Comment: Thanks, i thought it could work too :)   I checked xdebug manual but didn't see anything that could help. PHPStorm uses the standard one

Comment: @QuentinLerebours Please check these articles first in case if you have not seen them yet: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm -- there is also one about troubleshooting.

Comment: @RiggsFolly IDE does not need to use own php.ini -- it's actual PHP that executes your code so it lets PHP to decide what ini file to use. For web based debug (via browser) IDE has zero influence on server side xdebug/PHP configs -- only client ones (like local port number, for example)

Comment: @QuentinLerebours If breakpoint cannot be hit when it's on another file .. then most likely you are having issues with path mappings -- IDE cannot inform xdebug about right path to the file where you are trying to set the breakpoint. It could be because you have symlinks or alike in your path (remember: xdebug/PHP works with final/resolved paths while IDE uses them as is) ... or, if it's a remote debug (VM/another server), the path is completely different to local.

Comment: Sorry for the delay: @LazyOne This is not a pathmapping problem since I can move from file to file during 2 or 3 method calls.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I check the link you sent and i didn't find anything that could help me for the moment, thanks